# On Mac |Access data from chrome://settings/passwords VS passwords.google.com (chrome synced)

Tags: google-chrome, mac, sync, password-management

Chrome is synced to my google account. (fully, on Mac Big Sur and on an android phone)

Not working: On Mac, can't see a password in chrome://settings/passwords, It asks for my chrome ( see EDIT) password, and does *not* accept my google password (chrome is fully synced).

[ EDIT -> the password,request comes from Mac, that solves the issue ]

Also fingertip detection (on the mac), does not help.
( minor: the tiny window chrome opens to enter the chrome password, does not even have a show password option)

[ Edit -> not chrome opens that window it's Mac ]

Working well :

-Autofill

-Can see data (password) in passwords.google.com (using google password).

-Android's chrome-setting-passwords shows passwords (using phone's fingertip confirm)

Answer (score 0):

Ok, problem is related to Mac side.
That small window asking for password is from Mac-sw. And the password it asks for is the Mac device (not apple account) password.
( That's why it does not accept google's password ).